# Irridescent Subtile Glass Shader

Tags: texturing, glass

I would like to achieve such a result in Blender cycles[image]

My goal is to reach a glass texture with slight touches of irridescence. I figured out how to make something purely irridescent or purely glass but I didnt manage to give the impression of a slight irridescent touch. As if the irridescence was only on some little parts of my texture.

So please, if you got any hints it would be of great help. Many thanks, stay safe.